# How to change Hugo's generated html file path?

Tags: hugo

I'm using Hugo to generate my local Html help files.

when I type:

```
hugo new how-to-upgrade.md
```

What I'm expecting is a file named `how-to-upgrade.html` in the root folder. But actually I get `how-to-upgrade\index.html` file, with a folder and then a file in the folder.

I know it makes no difference using a web browser for `http://localhost:1313/how-to-upgrade/` or `http://localhost:1313/how-to-upgrade/index.html`. (actually, hugo server is jumping from the latter link to the former one.) But it makes big difference when openning the html files as local files.

`file:///C:/Users/Documents/hugo/public/how-to-upgrade/` will list all files in the folder like an old ftp site.

`file:///C:/Users/Documents/hugo/public/how-to-upgrade/index.html` is the html help file.

Now what I need is to generate local files like

`file:///C:/Users/Documents/hugo/public/how-to-upgrade.html`

without the folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the "uglyURLs" parameter to true on the command line or in your config file.